Why would the Empire lie to the Senate about a mining disaster on Jedha so close to the demise of the Senate
In Rogue One why would the Empire bother to lie to the Senate about a mining disaster on Jedha City less than one day before the Emperor dissolved the Senate?
Not long after the scene where Darth Vader Force-chokes Krennic and mentions the bogus mine disaster story to conceal the existence of the Death Star, Grand Moff Tarkin informs the Imperial top military brass that: "The Imperial Senate will no longer be of any concern to us. I've just received word that the Emperor has dissolved the council permanently. The last remnants of the Old Republic have been swept away... The regional governors now have direct control over their territories. Fear will keep the local systems in line. Fear of this battle station".
I would think that the destruction of Jedha City by the Death Star would have been the event that led to the demise of the Senate referenced in A New Hope – precisely because there was so little time in between the destruction of Jedha City and the termination of the Senate.
Instead, the Emperor and his top brass want to keep the Death Star hidden, within a day of terminating the Senate. That doesn't make sense to me.
